# Proof of function beeing surjective

Tags: functions, proof-writing

Maybe my question is trivial, but I'm new to rigorous math..so I hope you bear with me

I am currently working on a proof where I got the solution with some additional lemmas but I can't think of a proof by only deducing from the given facts:
Let $g : Y \rightarrow Z$ be a injective function and let $f : X \rightarrow Y$, prove that if $g \circ f$ is surjective then f is surjective.

My Approach was to prove that a) If $g \circ f$ is surjective then $g$ is surjective and b) if $f$ is surjective and $g$ is surjective then $g \circ f$ is surjective and use this information in the proof of my problem.

But I would like to see a direct approach. Could you give me a hint on how to tackle this?

Let $f, g$ be functions such that $g\circ f$ is surjective and g is injective. Let $y \in Y$...now I need to "find" an x such that f(x) = y, right? But how? We don't have that much information about f to say something about that x.

Comment: *Hint:* There exists $x \in X$ such that $g(f(x))=g(y)$. Now use that $g$ is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y \in Y$. Then $g(y) \in Z$ and since $g \circ f$ is surjective there exists an $x \in X$ such that $g(f(x)) = g(y)$. Since $g$ is injective this last statement implies that $f(x) = y$.